# Specified cast is invalid error, LINQ to Oracle table

Tags: c#, linq, oracle

Oracle column: user_id int not null,

Linq query:

```
UserId = user.Field<int>("user_id"),
```

UserId is int type.  Other string, char fields are workign fine, only when I use thsi field I get this error.

What is the correct mapping or anythign I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `Field<T>()` then that suggests you're using a `DataTable`, at which point the database type is mostly irrelevant. The exception should show you how the cast has failed - what the *actual* type is. If it doesn't, you can easily put some diagnostics in though:

```
object o = user["user_id"];
if (o == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("user_id is null");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Actual type of user_id: {0}", o.GetType());
}
```

I suspect you'll find it's `long` or `short`, or something like that - but this should show you for sure.

Comment: huh. Checked it, It is decimal. Was suspecting something of that sort. Thanks for your answer. weird that int DB column maps to decimal in dataTable.

Comment: @MunishGoyal: What *exactly* is the type in Oracle, and what does your SQL look like?

Comment: create table temp_user ( user_id int not null, ...)  It is int type

Comment: @MunishGoyal: Is `int` a synonym for `NUMBER(,)` in some form? If so, that may be what's causing the issues.